# How to return a string in a class based view using ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I want to transmit a string from a class based view to the client via ajax.

Here's my view, which inherits from another view

```
class TeamCreateView_Ajax(TeamCreateView):
    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("asdf")
```

For some reason, this transmits the entire web page that would've been rendered by `TeamCreateView` instead of the string "asdf".

```
class TeamCreateView_Ajax(TeamCreateView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse("asdf")
```

On the other hand, this correctly transmits "asdf".

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, using ajax, we communicate using either json/xml to send information from server to webpage. For example:

```
class SomeView(TemplateView): #I used template view because it has get method

    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):
                    data = {}
                    data['some_data'] = 'asdf'
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")
```

And in Script:

```
 $.ajax({  url: url,
           type: "get",
           success: function (data) {
             alert(data.some_data);
           })
```

Comment: I can't override the get() method because I have important logic embedded in my render_to_response method and overriding get() would bypass render_to_response()